# Modelbuilder tool referencing old filepath when run

Tags: modelbuilder, arcgis-pro, workspace

I built a ModelBuilder project for a client and am experiencing several issues related to the file paths.

Plainly put, when I relocate the geodatabase to a different file/drive SOME (but not all) tools are referencing the file path where they were first created, not the defined file path in the Input / Output dataset options in the tools.

My process was as follows:

- Created the geodatabase, input shapefiles, and model in ModelBuilder.
- Modified all of the file paths to use %Workspace%\xx_yy
- Compressed the project folder
- Relocate the folder to a different drive
- Extract, create new project
- Set the workspace as the location of the MOVED geodatabase
- Run

When I do that, sometimes the model attempts to input/output files from the original geodatabase location, ignoring the %workspace% defined.

I want to ensure that my client will be able to receive the database / models I provide them, set their workspace to that geodatabase, and run the models without issue.

[image: Error messages Seen]